# Как применить pytest для приложения Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, pytest

Впервые пишу тест, и делаю это для созданного с помощью Tkinter игрового приложения. Его основной функционал: пользователь задает любые вопросы и получает случайно выбранные ответы из имеющегося списка.
Ниже привожу краткий код, затем - вопрос по библиотеке pytest

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()

# создадим рамку, где будет поле для вопросов пользователя
frame_question_answer = tk.Frame(
    master=window, 
    relief=tk.RIDGE, 
    borderwidth=5
)
# создадим рамку, которая формирует область с  ответами на вопросы пользователя
frame_answer = tk.Frame(
    master=window, 
    relief=tk.RIDGE, 
    borderwidth=5
)
# добавим виджет Text - многострочный текстовый бокс (в противовес однострочному Entry)
# Данная область предназначена для написания вопросов
text_box_question = tk.Text(
    master=frame_question_answer_with_scroll,
    width=67, 
    height=5, 
    bg='#EBF1F2',
    fg='black'
)
# виджет для вывода случайных ответов 
text_box_answer = tk.Text(
    master = frame_answer_with_scroll,
    width=48, 
    height=7.5, 
    bg='#EBF1F2',
    fg='black'
)
# создадим элемент кнопки Спросить 
button_ask = tk.Button(
    master=frame_question_answer,
    text='Спросить',
    width=15,
    height=2,
    bg='#B533FF',
    fg='yellow',
    activebackground='#C4B1C3'
)
# создадим элемент кнопки Очистить 
button_clear = tk.Button(
    master=frame_question_answer,
    text='Очистить',
    width=15,
    height=2,
    bg='#B533FF',
    fg='yellow',
    activebackground='#C4B1C3'
)
frame_question_answer.grid(
    row=0, column=0,
    columnspan=1,
    sticky='e'                       
) 
frame_answer.grid(
    row=0, column=1, 
    columnspan = 1,     # дописал (этого нет в черновике): нормально - оставить
    sticky='w'                         
)
text_box_question.grid(
    row=0, column=0,                           
    sticky='news'                      
)
text_box_answer.grid(
    row=0, column=0, 
    sticky='news'                       
)
button_ask.grid(
    row=3, column=0, sticky='ew'
)
button_clear.grid(
    row=3, column=1, sticky='ew'
)
# Обработчик вопроса пользователя 
def questionQuery(event):
    question = text_box_question.get('1.0', tk.END) # читаем текст из виджета text_box_question
#     time.sleep(2)
    window.update_idletasks() 
    window.after(2000, lambda: button_ask.configure(text='Спросить')) 
    if not question.strip():
        text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Задайте свой вопрос\n') 
    else:
        answerQuery()
                    
# Функция возврата случайных ответов
def answerQuery():
    time.sleep(2)
#     window.after(2000, lambda: text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Хмм...' + '\n')) # и выводим в виджет text_box_answer
    text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Хмм...' + '\n') # и выводим в виджет text_box_answer
    window.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(2)
#     window.after(2000, lambda: text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Я заглядываю за повороты судьбы, чтобы узнать о грядущем' + '\n'))
    text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, 'Я заглядываю за повороты судьбы, чтобы узнать о грядущем' + '\n')
    window.update_idletasks()
    window.after(2000, lambda: text_box_answer.insert(tk.END, random.choice(responses) + '\n'))

# функция очистки полей вопроса и ответа 
def clearText(event):
    time.sleep(1)
    text_box_question.delete('1.0','end')
    time.sleep(1)
    text_box_answer.delete('1.0', tk.END)
button_ask.bind('<Button>', questionQuery)

# привязываем команду к кнопке очистки полей вопроса и ответа 
button_clear.bind('<Button>', clearText)

window.mainloop()
python
```

Теперь о pytest. Необходимо протестировать обе представленные функции. Для этого я создаю тестовый модуль, импортирую в него функцию и... Это открывает окно программы, но затем тест встает

```
from Magic_Ball_prog import questionQuery, answerQuery
def test_questionQuery():
    questionQuery('так?') == 'так?'

def test_answerQuery():
    pass
```

Какой же тест был бы корректен?
Хочу узнать, как функция реагирует на задаваемый вопрос, на пустую строку, как очищает ответы по кнопке "Очистить"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока напишу общие мысли по поводу тестирования GUI, позже постараюсь добавить какой-то минимальный пример

- Как минимум, проверки внутри теста должны выглядеть так: `assert questionQuery('так?') == 'так?'`, но это будет работать, только если функция что-то возвращает (у вас они ничего не возвращают, по сути возвращают `None`). У вас в процессе выполнения функции текст добавляется в текстовое поле, получается, что нужно будет из этого текстового поля текст получить, потом сравнить с предполагаемым результатом. Либо через mock (см. ниже) заменить метод `insert` текстового поля, и проверять, с какими параметрами он был вызван.
- Нужно будет добавить принудительное закрытие окна, чтобы тест когда-нибудь завершился (он у вас будет висеть пока выполняется метод `window.mainloop()`, а он выполняется пока существует окно).
- Возможно (но это не точно) придется переписать код через классы (классом нужно будет сделать главное окно, чтобы его можно было по запросу создавать/уничтожать)
- Не очень понятно, как тестировать функции, которые дают случайный результат, т.к. не понятно, с чем сравнивать. Как вариант, можно проверять по шаблону (начало текста - такое-то, конец - из такого-то списка).
- Немного проблематично тестировать, когда результат записывается через функцию обратного вызова (функцию, которая передается в метод `after` вторым параметром). Как вариант, можно через [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) (см. статью [Модуль Mock: макеты-пустышки в тестировании](https://habr.com/ru/post/141209/) (статья довольно старая, импорты могут отличаться, но для ознакомления пойдет)) заменить метод `after` на свою функцию, которая будет перехватывать что передается вторым параметром, и вызывать вручную без задержки.
- Вообще, можно заменить на mock все элементы управления, и само окно, потом только проверять, сколько раз с какими параметрами был вызван какой метод. В этом случае можно уничтожить настоящее окно сразу после создания, и дальше работать только со своими тестовыми объектами.

Comment: благодарю за развернутый комментарий. Из него сразу видна проблематика и некоторые варианты решения. Полезный текст. Если будут примеры, будет отилчно